# Recognizing random data extension by API

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api, dataextensions

Is there a way to check by API which of data extension is type of 'random'? I can't retrieve by SOAP type property of data extension. Thanks for help.

Comment: I'm not seeing this as a property in the SOAP API docs and, based on my past experience with random/filtered DE's through the API, selecting by type is not available.